# react window with Autosizer

Tags: reactjs, react-window

I got a problem when I used react-window with react-virtualized-auto-sizer, I made a little change of official example, then the list is disappear. I wonder why?
Thank you for any help ~~

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bvaughn-react-window-fixed-size-list-vertical-forked-utczn?file=/index.js

when you delete the `div` node in the `Example`component, everything is ok.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem here is that the parent node, in that case, the `<div>` element, should have a `height`
Take a look at this, its working:

```
<div style={{display: "flex", flexGrow: 1, height: "100%"}}>
    <AutoSizer>
       // your code
    </AutoSizer>
</div>
```

There is an old issue about this, take a look:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/570

Comment: Thanks! 
In my case I needed to pass a fixed height and worked like a charm.